# "this" is not referencing the data object inside Meteor event

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor template event `click .menuItem` failed to print out the value of the property `menuShortName` when the `li` is clicked. How can I get that value when I click the list item?
Please see the image at the bottom showing the collection documents.

```js
Template.mainMenu.helpers({
  menuItems: () => {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      return MenuItemsCol.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: 1}});
    }
  }
});

Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': (event) => {
    let menuShortName = this.menuShortName;
    console.log(menuShortName);
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  {{> header}}
  {{#if currentUser}}
    {{#if isVerified}}
      {{> index}}  // <--------------------------- 
    {{else}}
      <br><br><br><br>
      <p>Check your email for your verification link!</p>
    {{/if}}
  {{else}}
    {{> terms}}
  {{/if}}
</body>

<template name="index">
  <div id="main">
    {{#if (display 'mainMenu')}}
      {{> mainMenu}}  // <--------------------------- 
    {{else}}
      {{> content}}
      {{#if (session 'showFooter')}}
        {{> footer}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="mainMenu">  // <--------------------------- 
  <div id="mainMenu">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="list-group">
         {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
          {{#each menuItems}}
            <li data-template="{{menuItem}}" role="presentation">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item menuItem">
                <img src="/{{image}}.svg"/>
                {{menuItem}}
              </a>
            </li>
          {{/each}}
         {{//if}}
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In blaze the event handler function gets passed 2 parameters, the event, and the instance of template on which the event was fired.

The event object has a reference to the target (the DOM element)

You can assign the data to the element which you are listening the event on (not the parent):

```
<template name="mainMenu">  // <--------------------------- 
  <div id="mainMenu">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="list-group">
         {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
          {{#each menuItems}}
            <li role="presentation">
              <a data-template="{{menuItem}}" href="#" class="list-group-item menuItem">
                <img src="/{{image}}.svg"/>
                {{menuItem}}
              </a>
            </li>
          {{/each}}
         {{//if}}
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

(note: I moved the data- attribute in the anchor)

and access it like this:

```
Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': (event) => {
    let menuShortName = event.currentTarget.dataset.template;
    console.log(menuShortName);
  }
});
```

Comment: `event.currentTarget.value` prints out `undefined` in the console

Comment: Your event listener is on an anchor tag, which doesn't have a value (is not a form field). In your case, you can simply read the innerHTML of the event target. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: that gives the "<img src="/video.svg"> Videos - How to"  but not the menuShortName

Comment: Move the data attribute in the element which you are listening events for, and fetch the value from it.

Comment: I did `<li data-template="{{menuShortName}}" role="presentation">` and used your updated answer, still getting 'undefined` printed to the console. I wonder if the data is loaded when the page is rendered... hummm